# Checking if an object is listening to a KVO key path

Tags: ios, key-value-observing

Am I missing something or is there no way to check if a given object is registered for a given KVO keypath?

NSManagedObject defines the observationInfo method, but the returned object structure seems to be private - of little use unless you simply want to log it to the console.

Comment: Why do you need to know this? There probably is a better way to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump out the list of observers like this:

```
 [myObject observationInfo];
```

That will list all the objects that are observing myObject.

Comment: Thanks, but did mention that in my question above. Since the contents are effectively private, it's only really useful for debugging on the console, rather checking and acting programatically.

Comment: @AndrewEbling - I was referring to the NSKeyValueObserving Protocol, but I guess that's the same thing.  I don't see anything that says it's private though.

Comment: The classes which make up the object graph returned by observationInfo are not documented anywhere, hence the information should be deemed private.